# spray like tool performance in paperjs

Tags: svg, paperjs

I'm trying to code a spray like tool in paperjs because the drawing must be svg exportable.

The code is working but the performance gets bad very quickly. Is there a way to mimic a svg exportable spray like tool with improved performance in paperjs or another library?

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">

var path;
var gradient = {
    stops: [
        ['rgba(0,0,0,1)', 0],
        ['rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', 0.5],
        ['rgba(0,0,0,0)', 1]
    ],
    radial: true
};

tool.minDistance = 5;
tool.maxDistance = 5;

function onMouseDown(event) {
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {

    path = new Path.Circle({
        center: event.point,
        radius: 10
    });

    path.fillColor = {
        gradient: gradient,
        origin: path.position,
        destination: path.bounds.rightCenter
    };

}

function onMouseUp(event) {
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var svg = project.exportSVG({ asString: true });

    console.log('data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg));

});

</script>
```

update1: fixed gradient var scope, due to suggestion, but the problem persists.

update2: proper use of tool.

Comment: best use a single gradient created outside the loop (since the gradient doesn't change) and make all the paths refer to that single gradient.

Answer (score 1):

for svg i prefer http://snapsvg.io/ 
for export svg using paper.js could you disable asString and check the performance , cause may be the string added to the DOM very large which produce this lag

Answer (score 1):

Since all Items have the same shape, you should use [Symbols](http://paperjs.org/reference/symboldefinition/) in Paper.js. This reduces overhead significantly, because internally the same path will be used for all displayed items.

[Here is a Sketch to try](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/fVPBbsIwDP2VqBeKVEXlwCVoJ7jsMGkS2gk4pK1bIlIHOSlsQvz7krK2K2ykclXbr/Z7T8olQllDJKL1AVy+j5IoN0XIT5JYRbJQgI69sMuWtsj8sc4crWCbLg9nM6Eqk3GahGc2nSQs3SX/AlI+byF8/gwUILNd1x+QgZLUgjlqINSui/AO4YzRvFa4UtZJzMGzni+Ghvx8aIQIOjPdEEGxVJTr0EU4s3fp9vxWiXvxuTcDyKtPRxIDp8abMkv7kkIL5AQrpbY3ntN+5WgdL5XWS6MN/Xa5c170X/1kQ6pSKMak+dFY5ZTBHlaAdQplqN1jM9NgYbmfs3fLVtHYyAdLVlD+uLL+qjOjfa6wXRePcIPELsoG84BjBt9MY2FlzhjDyS+d3sRe/0WSrEZIr2lg8Oqgju85JqzFey+U/2vxdPzH8W8a/gJkBPLQzrCR2Oyu3w==)

And here is your code using Symbols:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">

var gradient = {
    stops: [
        ['rgba(0,0,0,1)', 0],
        ['rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', 0.5],
        ['rgba(0,0,0,0)', 1]
    ],
    radial: true
};

tool.minDistance = 5;
tool.maxDistance = 5;

var blurredCircle = new Path.Circle({
    center: [0, 0],
    radius: 10,
    insert: false
});

blurredCircle.fillColor = {
    gradient: gradient,
    origin: blurredCircle.position,
    destination: blurredCircle.bounds.rightCenter
};

var blurredCircleDef = new SymbolDefinition(blurredCircle);


function onMouseDown(event) {
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
   new SymbolItem(blurredCircleDef, event.point);
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var svg = project.exportSVG({ asString: true });

    console.log('data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg));

});

</script>
```